# Create an automatic routine to run several python script, using a shell script

Tags: python, linux, shell, automation

I am trying to create a shell script that executes some python scripts in order.
I have never done something like this and i don´t know if what i am doing is correct.
Before executing the last file i need to activate an enviroment so it has the necesary imports to so it functions correctly.
This is the script i have created (execute.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
python path/file_1.py
python path/file_2.py
python path/file_3.py
# activate a virtual enviroment
source /path/env/bin/activate
python path/file_4.py
```

After this what sould I do?
Just write this line in the terminal?

`./execute.sh`

Comment: Don't forget to *chmod +x ./execute.sh* and then you should be good to go

Comment: I'm assuming your shell scipt is execute.sh. Firstly you must go into the files properties and mark the file as executable. Right click on file name and select Permission tab and click on Allow executing file as program. Then you can open terminal in the folder you file resides an type ./execute.sh OR you can double click on file in nemo and select run

Comment: If you don't make _execute.sh_  executable, you can still run it by doing a `sh ./execute.sh`. This is up to you.

Comment: @GalodoLeste : (1) What is _nemo_? (2) The OP does not specify what GUI he uses (if any). How can you know that there is something like a _permission tab_ available?

Comment: Nemo is the file manager for linux mint. Read linux tag and interpreted linux mint. It was late  after a long day.

Comment: @user1934428 yes, i intended to make the file executable, but it is good to know tha other way works to, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work. Usually I always do this when running a bash script with Python scripts inside.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

. /home/user/.bashrc # Load basic env as we're coming from cron

# Cd into our working directory in case we're not into it already
cd "$(dirname "$0")";

echo "----------------"
echo "Starting processing `date`"
echo "----------------"

conda activate models # Activate my conda environment

# Execute Python script
python script.py

if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then
    echo "Succesfull execution!"
else
    echo "Something wrong"
    exit 1
fi
```

This is in execute.run, which you then make executable `chmod +x executable.run`, and run. This will work wherever you are because it will always try to cd into the directory where the script resides, so you can also call it from crontab.

Comment: Why is the extension from the file '.run'?

Comment: The extension is not really important.. Once you make a file executable it will be run in the same way and according to the shebang that you put in the script.